# findElement is not working in Appium on Android

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, mobile, automation, appium

I am trying to click on display button in Settings app.
But "findElementBy.." statement is not working, Sometimes I get 'nullpointer exception' or 'no such element exist' exception and some times test passes without clicking Display button.

[image: Click to View Image]

I have tried with different application but still the findElementBy... is not working in Win10.
But the same piece of code is working, when I run it on the same real device from my Win 7 laptop.

**Project is using following jars:**

1. gson-2.2.2.jar
2. java-client-4.1.2.jar
3. selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
4. Android Development Tool for Eclipse (addon)
5. Android for Maven Eclipse 1.4.0 (addon)
6. Appium Sever (ver: 1.4.13.1)

**Appium Code:**

```
@Test
public void Script1() throws Exception{

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator 2");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi 3S");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.settings");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.settings.MainSettings");

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    Thread.sleep(5000); 
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().text(\"Display\")").click();
}
```

I have already tried different types of Locators (i.e ByID, ClassPath, xpath, UISelector etc.) but nothing worked on win 10 machine. I dont think so there is an Issue of locators because they are working on my win7 laptop.

Appium Logs:

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>
> warn: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please upgrade!
>
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)
>
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
>
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.android.settings","appActivity":"com.android.settings.MainSettings","platformVersion":"6.0.1","automationName":"UiAutomator 2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Redmi 3S"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.android.settings","appActivity":"com.android.settings.MainSettings","platformVersion":"6.0.1","automationName":"UiAutomator 2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Redmi 3S"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android"},"firstMatch":[]}}
>
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_144)
>
> info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d
>
> info: Starting android appium
>
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
>
> info: Java version is: 1.8.0_144
>
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>
> warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
>
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>
> info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>
> info: Retrieving device
>
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>
> info: Found device 964aa907d030
>
> info: [debug] Setting device id to 964aa907d030
>
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 wait-for-device
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "echo 'ready'"
>
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>
> info: Device API level is: 23
>
> info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>
> info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
>
> info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
>
> info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>
> info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
>
> info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>
> info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>
> info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>
> info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
>
> info: Starting App
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>
> info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>
> info: [debug] No matching processes found
>
> info: [debug] Running bootstrap
>
> info: [debug] spawning: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 964aa907d030 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.android.settings -e disableAndroidWatchers false
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
>
> info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
>
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "dumpsys window"
>
> info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
>
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"/data/local/tmp"}
>
> info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
>
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":false}
>
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.MainSettings"
>
> info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.android.settings" and activity "com.android.settings.MainSettings" to be focused
>
> info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "dumpsys window windows"
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
>
> info: [debug] Device is at release version 6.0.1
>
> info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
>
> info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
>
> info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d
>
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 6622.421 ms - 74
>
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d {}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.android.settings","appActivity":"com.android.settings.MainSettings","platformVersion":"6.0.1","automationName":"UiAutomator 2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Redmi 3S"},"appPackage":"com.android.settings","appActivity":"com.android.settings.MainSettings","automationName":"UiAutomator 2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"964aa907d030"},"sessionId":"44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d"}
>
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d 200 1.705 ms - 695 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"6.0.1","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"com.android.settings","appActivity":"com.android.settings.MainSettings","platformVersion":"6.0.1","automationName":"UiAutomator 2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Redmi 3S"},"appPackage":"com.android.settings","appActivity":"com.android.settings.MainSettings","automationName":"UiAutomator 2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"964aa907d030"},"sessionId":"44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d"}
>
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d/element {"using":"-android uiautomator","value":"UiSelector().text(\"Display\")"}
>
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
>
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"UiSelector().text(\"Display\")","context":"","multiple":false}]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"UiSelector().text(\"Display\")","context":"","multiple":false}}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding UiSelector().text("Display") using ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR with the contextId:  multiple: false
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Parsing selector: UiSelector().text("Display")
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "Display"
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[TEXT=Display]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"}}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d"}
>
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d/element 200 82.340 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d"}
>
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d/element/1/click {"id":"1"}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"1"}]
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"1"}}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d"}
>
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d/element/1/click 200 40.169 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"44f52f68-60a6-4469-9575-0c1bfe2d999d"}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
>
> info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...
>
> info: Shutting down appium session
>
> info: [debug] Pressing the HOME button
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 964aa907d030 shell "input keyevent 3"
>
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>
> info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
>
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 67.859
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
>
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>
> info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
>
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>
> info: [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in

Comment: Just got a solution by adding dependencies using maven project.

Answer (score 0):

You just try it: `driver.findElement(By.ByName("Display"));`

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Display']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

driver.findElementByName("Display").click();

or

driver.findElementByxpath("//*[@id='android:id/title'][@text='Display']").click();

it should work